# Tinymce - pasting content removes classes

Tags: javascript, paste, tinymce-4

Copying content from editor and pasting in editor, removing classes from other already existing elements. I'm not even getting an idea why its happening. Any help?

Comment: This is very likely due to a configuration setting in TinyMCE.  Can you create a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this happening?  It helps people if you create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFromin. Actually i missed class attribute for P tag in extended_valid_elements, thats why pasting the content was removing class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce version 5 vs 6, I use this:

```
var stripAttributes = function(html) {
  var tags = html.match(/(<\/?[\S][^>]*>)/gi);
  tags.forEach(function(tag){
    // Remove "class" attributes
    var noClass = tag.replace(/(class=".*?")|(class='.*?')|(class=[^\s>]*)/gi, '');

    // Remove "id" attributes
    var noID = noClass.replace(/(id=".*?")|(id='.*?')|(id=[^\s>]*)/gi, '');

    // Remove "data-" attributes
    var noData = noID.replace(/(data-.+?=".*?")|(data-.+?='.*?')|(data-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/gi, '');
    // Update html string
    html = html.replace(tag, noData);
  });
  return html;
};
```

And:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'paste',
  paste_tab_spaces: 2,
 paste_preprocess : (editor, args) => {
            console.log("before" , args.content);
            args.content  = stripAttributes(args.content);
            console.log("after" , args.content);
        },
});
```